# DotNetZip check if folder exists in zip file

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

I am trying to check if a folder exists in a zip file. The code is following:

```
//All entries refered too exists.
//For files (Workes fine, returns true)
var hello1 = zip.Any(entry => entry.FileName.Equals(@"Patients.xml"));
var hello2 = zip.Any(entry => entry.FileName.Equals(@"Bookings.xml"));

//For folders (Dosent work (returns false))
var result1 = zip.Any(entry => entry.FileName.Equals(@"PatientsF"));
var result2 = zip.Any(entry => entry.FileName.Equals(@"U14"));
```

I have tryed with:

```
entry.FileName.Contains(@"PatientsF"));
```

And that works, but i want to get the folder with the exact name "PatientsF". With the code "Contains" it would return true if the name just have "PatientsF". How should i fix this?

Any help will be appreciated. thanks in advance.

PS. If i'm unclear somewhere, or if you need more information then just explain what's needed.

Comment: you could check the filename length also

Comment: Thanks Sayse, the trick worked, if the lenght have to be 9 (10 in the code, dont know why.) then there is no way that other folders can have the same name. But is there a more secure way?

Comment: Select every directory with entry.IsDirectory == true. Output them in the console see what their "real" names are. You now know what on filter on, instead of wild guessing :D.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Then expand on what does work to make it sure to find a folder:

```
entry.FileName.Contains("PatientsF/"));
```

The `/` is a path delimiter, so it *cannot* be part of a filename.

Comment: Sorry, With "\" it does not even find the folder.

Comment: Remove the first \ so try this `entry.FileName.Contains(@"PatientsF\"));`

Comment: foreach (ZipEntry zip in objSourceZipfileCheck)
 {
 if(zip.FileName.Contains("/"))
 {
 folder there
 }
 }

Comment: @KamranShahid That wouldn't work for me.  In my case, when I inspect my ZIP collection of entries, I see that every one starts with `ZipEntry/` followed by the sub-path of the file itself.  So for example:  `ZipEntry/MyFolder/MyFile.txt`.  So you'd simply flag every entry in error.

Comment: hmm.It works for me.Looks like i have to recheck the code or my zip file structure.or may i need your zip file

Comment: @KamranShahid It is also possible that not every implementation of ZIP structure is the same. For the record, OP is using the DotNetZip library, and I am using Ionic.Zip.

Comment: As far as i know ionic zip and dotnetzip are same see 
http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/